# работа с shortcodes в WP

Tags: php, wordpress

пишу код на страничке:

```
[button url="http://www/?page_id=149"  button_css="margin-top: 10px" ]Read more[/button]
```

браузер выводит:

```
<p><a class="bd-button" href="/" >Read more</a><br />
```

и на указанную мною ссылку не реагирует.
в шаблоне в shortcodes нашел:

```
// Button
    public static function button($atts, $content='') {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'link' => '/',
            'type' => 'default',
            'style' => '',
            'size' => '',
            'icon' => ''
        ), $atts));

        $classNames = 'bd-button';
        $linkContent = $content;
        $styles = array('default' => 'btn-default', 'primary' => 'btn-primary', 'success' => 'btn-success',
            'info' => 'btn-info', 'warning' => 'btn-warning', 'danger' => 'btn-danger', 'link' => 'btn-link');
        $sizes = array('large' => 'btn-lg', 'small' => 'btn-sm', 'xsmall' => 'btn-xs');

        if ($type === 'bootstrap') {
            $classNames = 'btn';
            array_key_exists(strtolower($style), $styles) ? $classNames .= ' ' . $styles[strtolower($style)] : '';
            array_key_exists(strtolower($size), $sizes) ? $classNames .= ' ' . $sizes[strtolower($size)] : '';
        }

        if ($icon !== '') {
            $linkContent = '<span class="' . esc_attr($icon) . '">&nbsp;</span>' . $linkContent;
        }

        return '<a class="' . $classNames . '" href="' . esc_attr($link) . '">' . $linkContent . '</a>';
    }
```

подскажите что тут менять что бы реагировал на вписываюмую мною ссылку.
Спасибо!

Comment: судя по всему вместо `url` надо `link` использовать, а вместо `button_css` надо `style` вставить

Comment: спасибо link помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
[button url="http://www/?page_id=149"  button_css="margin-top: 10px" ]Read more[/button]
```

а следуя из кода должно быть

```
[button link="?page_id=149"  style="margin-top: 10px" ]Read more[/button]
```